# Flutter Console Windows Batch File Not Opening

Tags: flutter

I have recently downloaded `flutter` from [here](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/) and followed the setup instructions after extraction. I have set the path in environment variable to `C:\Flutter\flutter` at the root of my C drive.

The problem then occurs when I try opening `flutter_console` batch file as specified in the docs. The terminal window only flashes open and disappears, sometimes when it manages to be stable, a key stroke will send it closing again.

I want to know if anyone else is facing this and how we can resolve this issue.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use the flutter commands in the powershell or CMD?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work still

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The flutter console just flashes. It doesn't open and I have even set the path properly the code "flutter doctor" doesn't work either. I have installed git too.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should be adding your `<flutter install directory>/flutter/bin;` to the path not the flutter directory. Then you should be able to use flutter from cmd/powershell. If you have a window open before changing the environment variable either reopen it or run `refreshenv`.

If that still isn't working, there's something seriously weird going on here. Try opening a cmd window, going to the flutter directory, and running `flutter_console.bat` from there. And you could try pasting your path so we can see if theres anything wrong with it (run `echo %PATH%` from a command prompt to see it, but you should anything personal before posting it).

Comment: I have fixed the flutter path issue but now its showing this error - 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

Comment: Ah. Well you should install git, I guess they thought everyone would already have it so didn't include it in the instructions. https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: Already have and use git, still showing that error even after setting the path in environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. And there is a very simple fix. Just run the flutter console as Administrator. It will work just fine. Run the power shell also as Administrator. When you are trying to do the `flutter doctor` It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding C:\windows\system32 to the PATH system variable

Answer (score 0):

the flutter console and the flutter doctor command will work in your terminal if you run it as an administrator, but the real way to fix this issue is adding  the route: C:\windows\system32 to the PATH system variable

Answer (score 0):

**Add** the following to your **path** variable

C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32; C:\Windows\SysWOW64;

Once done make sure you are opening **flutter_console.bat** and/or **command prompt** using  admin rights. I hope its gonna work then after!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are using window PowerShell version 5 or above.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same problem, but it is resolved now!
You can first check the cmd (command prompt ) in the

```
c:->windows->system32->cmd
```

if it is not present in this location then copy the cmd where it is currently present (in my case it was present in
`C:->windows->SysWOW64`  to this  `c:->windows->system32->cmd` location .

It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are searching for flutter console and then clicking on it
it will flashes
you should search for flutter_console
or go to your flutter folder and click on it from there